# Best ergonomic setup posture for people who can't touch type?

Tags: work-environment, working-conditions, ergonomics

The standard for office ergonomics (screen position, keyboard position, chair height etc.) seem to be based on people who touch type.

I cannot touch type - how should I organize my workplace?

Comment: What items does your workplace have? Do you have a laptop or desktop (important as per the keyboard you have). Number of screens available?

Comment: Just a desktop with one screen (or to be more precise a pc tower and a screen on a cradle

Comment: You should learn how to type blind, it is no good to alter posture to fit a bad habit. Now, your light source should come from your left mostly. Given you cant type blind I suppose the most comfortable would be to put pc and keyboard aligned in front of you. Another option is to place keyboard in front and screen a bit to your right, but this is better with blind typing.

Comment: Does _now I cannot touch type_ mean you used to be able to, and are unable to do so anymore?

Comment: No was never able to blind type if I try I make a mess

Comment: @Willemien: I edited out "when I cannot touch type" which was causing confusion, like maybe it meant you can touch type some of the time, but not when on the phone, slouching back, injured etc. Now says "for people who can't touch type".

Comment: Other necessary information: a) there are different sorts of typing, are you data entry, writing English, programming...? b) do you use a keytray or not? c) how much mousing do you do? Do you have an ergo mouse with back and zoom side-buttons?

Comment: This doesn't speak directly to 'touch type', but a guy I know wrote article called Back pain relief, office ergonomics that you might find useful.  Good luck.   https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/18447/Back-pain-relief-office-ergonomics.html

Answer (score 13):

I can't touch type to any degree of skill,  But that doesn't stop me from using the same posture as everyone else.

I've been doing this for more years than I care to remember and it's not given me any problems.

So, just do the same as everyone else does.  If doing so makes you physically uncomfortable, then change your ergonomics (chair height/monitor height/whatever) until you are comfortable.

Answer (score 3):

**The posture should be the same regardless of typing method**

Not slouching in your chair and ensuring your wrists are not bent have nothing to do with typing method.  The reason you should sit straight in your chair with your feet on the floor and wrists straight is to prevent back and wrist issues.

Answer (score 0):

The *ergonomic recommendations don't change* based on whether you touch type.

If you do not want to learn to touch type then **at least** don't rest your wrists on the keyboard.
That will mess you up in the long run! (In layman's terms cocking your writs tightens the tendons and makes them "wear out faster". Feel free to comment with the correct medical terms.)

Learning to touch type is simple (not saying it is easy)

Keep your left hand on `ASDF` and your right on `JKL;`
Often your index finger keys ("A" and "J") will have a little bump on them to let you know you are in the correct position.

Do your best. Glance down when you need to find a letter.
Learn the letters and the semi-colon first.

That's as far as I've gotten... I still can't touch type numbers/dashes/ brackets/braces / etc.  ;-)